# Why not getUriFromFile in StreamProvider?

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac, android-fileprovider

I'm using https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider to share files stored in "getExternalFilesDir", because Android FileProvider has no tag for this (although the documentation says it has, you know it's an old mistake in such documentation)

I understand that not every content shared with StreamProvider is a file, but having a "getUriFromFile" method would be useful. Since there is no such method, do I need to create the uris "manually"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since there is no such method, do I need to create the uris "manually"?

Yes.

> I understand that not every content shared with StreamProvider is a file

Which is why I elected not to attempt to create such a method, at least at the present time.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response